# How to match a word(String) in URL

Tags: java, regex, url, pattern-matching, string-matching

This website contains different Url, But i want my application should vist urls only which contains specific keyword like "drugs" like
if urls are

http://website.com/countryname/drug/info/A

http://website.com/countryname/Browse/Alphabet/D?cat=company

it should visit first URL.so how to match a specific keyword drug in url.I know it can be done using regexp also,but have but i am new to it
I am using Java here

Comment: Use the Contains() method of the string class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check if string contains a word with method contains().
`if(myString.contains("drugs"))`
If you need only URLs containing /drug/ try to do something like this:

```
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("/drug(/|$)");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(myURLString);
    if(m.find())
    {
        something_to_do
    }
```

`(/|$)` means that after `/drug` can be only a slash ( / ) or nothing at all (dollar means end of the line).So this regex will find all if your string is like `.../drug/...` or `.../drug`

Comment: The problem with that is that it will also match, say, `drugstore`

Answer (score 0):

Use `split()` as such:

```
final String[] words = input.replaceFirst("https?://", "").split("/+");
for (final String word: words)
    if ("whatyouwant".equals(word))
       //do what is necessary since the word matches
```

If your code is called very often, you may want to make `Pattern`s out of `https?://` and `/+` and use `Matcher`s.